# Recurring Meeting Request WITH VOTING BUTTONS

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to send an email weekly inquiring about the status of a project.  There are 4 possible statuses that a PM can choose from.  Right now I have a recurring meeting request being sent requesting that they REPLY with the status but I want to  make it so that all they have to do is use the voting buttons when the reminder comes up weekly.  Is this possible in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, it is not possible. The voting buttons is for one meeting or one recurring meeting.

One workaround is to pre-create the meeting request, enter in the voting options, then delay delivery until a certain date and time.

I think another approach is to delegate tasks to the responsible party and let them update five different statuses along with percentage from 0% to 100%.